# Ratio of area of two similar polygons

Tags: geometry

So the two corresponding sides of these two similar polygons have lengths $3$ and $7$. The perimeter of the larger one (one that has $7$ as a side, presumably) is $91$ cm. What's the perimeter of the smaller polygon, and what's the ratio of their areas? I'm thinking the perimeter of the smaller one is $\frac 37$ of $90$ ($38.57$) but just like my last question, it needs to be in the form of a radical such as $3\sqrt{5}$. Am I also right in thinking that the ratio of their areas needs to be $3:7$?

Comment: If you scale linear dimensions (lengths, perimeters) by the factor $s$, you scale areas by the factor $s^2$. And you scale volumes by the factor $s^3$.

Comment: If you already asked a question previously, you must be knowing that this site uses LateX. Please try to frame the questions keeping formatting in mind. As far as the answer goes, I think it cannot be a radical, since a radical is an irrational number. The answer you get is a rational, similar to your last question. The areas though, would be in $3^2:7^2 = 9:49$ ratio.

Comment: Think about a square.  If you have two similar squares, i.e., a square with side length $a$ and a square with side length $b$, then the sides are in ratio $a:b$ while the areas are in ratio $a^2:b^2$.